# Parsing valid JSON using $.ajax() results in "parseerror"

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm having a problem parsing a JSON string located at the URL below:

http://sandbox.stevenmclintock.com/json/bookmarks

I've included my jQuery $.ajax() call but can't seem to figure out why it returns "parse error"? It validates in JSONLint so I was hoping someone on here could give me a hand?

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/json/bookmarks',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
    },
    error: function (qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as `dataType: 'application/json',`. The `dataType` parameter can be `html`, `text`, `xml`, `json`, ...

So you could just use:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

or since the server correctly sets the `Content-Type` response header to `application/json` you could completely get rid of this `dataType` parameter from your AJAX request because jQuery is intelligent enough to use this response header from the server:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/json/bookmarks',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

Comment: To add to his answer. [P.S. Your current JSON string is properly formatted] You can always verify your JSON formatting online. Try http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/